# Parallel search of distinct values?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, parallel-processing, mutex

Consider the following code :

```
// Preprocessor
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>

// Main function
int main()
{
    // A random vector of size 100 with 10 different random values
    std::vector<unsigned int> vector = make_random_vector(100, 10);
    // At the end, the result should be the 10 different random values
    std::vector<unsigned int> result;
    // Mutex to deals with concurrency
    std::mutex mutex;
    // Parallel search
    parallel_for_each(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 
    [=, &result, &mutex](const unsigned int& i){
       /* CRITICAL SECTION: BEGIN */
       // If the current element is not yet in the resulting vector, inserts it
       if (!std::binary_search(result.begin(), result.end(), i)) {
           mutex.lock();
           result.insert(std::lower_bound(result.begin(), result.end(), i), i);
           mutex.unlock();
       }
       /* CRITICAL SECTION: END */
    });
    // Unique values
    result.erase(std::unique(result.begin(), result.end()), result.end());
    // Display the result
    std::for_each(result.begin(), result.end(), 
    [](const unsigned int& i){
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    });
    // Finalization
    return 0;
}
```

The goal is to find the n distinct values in a vector in parallel.

**My question is : is the preceding code OK (no problem of concurrency), and if not, how to correct it ?**

---

Note: this code has calls to two functions :

`parallel_for_each` which executes the provided function on the provided number of threads :

```
// Parallel execution returning the execution time in seconds
template <class Iterator, class Function> 
double parallel_for_each(const Iterator& first, const Iterator& last, Function&& function, const int nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
{
    const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tbegin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const long long int ntasks = std::max(static_cast<int>(1), nthreads);
    const long long int group = std::max(static_cast<long long int>(first < last), static_cast<long long int>((last-first)/ntasks));
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    Iterator it = first;
    threads.reserve(ntasks);
    for (it = first; it < last-group; it += group) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread([=, &last, &group, &function](){std::for_each(it, std::min(it+group, last), function);}));
    }
    std::for_each(it, last, function);
    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](std::thread& current){current.join();});
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-tbegin).count();
}
```

`make_random_vector` which produces a random vector of nelements with nvalues different random values

```
// Produces a random vector of nelements with nvalues different random values
std::vector<unsigned int> make_random_vector(const unsigned int nelements, const unsigned int nvalues)
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> vector(nelements);
    std::vector<unsigned int> values(nvalues);
    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 engine(device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> distribution1;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> distribution2(0, nvalues-1);
    std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), [=, &distribution1, &engine](unsigned int& i){i = distribution1(engine);});
    std::for_each(vector.begin(), vector.end(), [=, &distribution2, &engine, &values](unsigned int& i){i = values[distribution2(engine)];});
    return vector;
}
```

Comment: If `result.insert` causes a reallocation of the vector, while another thread is performing a `binary_search` on it, bad things are going to happen. I feel the only way to do this is to have each task to return a vector of results, and then merge the results from each thread.

Comment: If the vector is much larger than the cache size, then the searching will be memory bandwidth limited, and the parallel approach may not help much. Parallel approach will help if a process is CPU bandwidth limited or when most of the operations take place within the local cache for each core (note that the outer cache is shared between cores on some CPUs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has problem, as you only protect concurrent write access but not read access of `result`.

A solution would be to move the mutex locking outside of the `if` as follow:

```
[=, &result, &mutex](const unsigned int& i){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck (mutex);

    // If the current element is not yet in the resulting vector, inserts it
    if (!std::binary_search(result.begin(), result.end(), i)) {
        result.insert(std::lower_bound(result.begin(), result.end(), i), i);
    }
}
```

but it will break the purpose of the parallel for :/

An other solution would be to work on different result set, and join the result at the end of the loop.

An other solution may be a variant of [Double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) but requires to copy `result` at each insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `std::vector<unsigned int>`  use `Concurrency::combinable<std::vector<unsigned int>> result`. This allows to have thread local copy of result and you don't need any mutex.

Once done with the `parallel_for_each` use `combine_each` and put the result in a `std::set<unsigned int>` to get the unique values or whichever way you think is appropriate.

**EDIT:** The below approach does not require std::mutex.

```
 #include <ppl.h>

 void print_unqiue_numbers()
 {
    using namespace Concurrency;
    std::vector<unsigned int> vector = make_random_vector(100, 10);
    // At the end, the result should be the 10 different random values
    combinable<std::vector<unsigned int>> result;
    // Parallel search
    parallel_for_each(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 
    [=, &result](const unsigned int& i){
       auto& local_result = result.local(); // thread local variable.
       if (!std::binary_search(local_result.begin(), local_result.end(), i)) {
           local_result.insert(std::lower_bound(local_result.begin(),
                                                local_result.end(), i), i);
       }
    });

     std::set<unsigned int> unique_values;
     result.combine_each([&](std::vector<unsigned int> const& values)
     {
        for(auto v : values)
        {
            unique_values.insert(v);
        }
     });

     std::cout << "print the unique values\n";
     for (auto v : unique_values)
     {
         std::cout << v << '\n';
     }
  }
```